# Flywaydb - ERROR: invalid transaction termination

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, flyway

I am trying to update a large amount of data using batch.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_table()
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
-- variable declaration
    total_records int;
    batch_size    int := 100000; 
    counter       int := 0;
BEGIN

    SELECT INTO total_records COUNT(*)
    FROM login l
    WHERE .........;

    RAISE INFO 'Total records to be updated %', total_records;

    WHILE counter <= total_records
        LOOP
            RAISE INFO 'Start -id- of row : % , in the iteration .', counter;
            UPDATE login lup
            SET updated_field = true
            FROM login_to_be_updated luptemp
            WHERE luptemp.id = lup.id 
              AND luptemp.row_id > counter
              AND luptemp.row_id <= counter + batch_size;
            COMMIT;

            counter := counter + batch_size;

        END LOOP;

END;
$$;
```

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE login_to_be_updated AS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) row_id, id
FROM login l
WHERE .........;
```

```sql
CALL update_login();
```

With manual startup, everything works.

When using flywaydb , I get an error:

> Caused by:
> org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException:
> Migration V12.157.04__run_procedure.sql failed
> --------------------------------------------------------------- SQL State  : 2D000 Error Code : 0 Message    : ERROR: invalid transaction
> termination   Where: PL/pgSQL function update_login() line 30 at
> COMMIT Location   :
> db/migration/12/V12__run_procedure.sql
> (/Users/...../build/resources/main/db/migration/12/V12__run_procedure.sql)
> Line       : 1 Statement  : CALL update_login()

Who has any ideas how to fix it and why it happens ?

The number of updated records, several tens of millions.